# JQuery Display Alert Message on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to display alert messages on jquery from the client side. The jquery will be called once the submit button is clicked. The form then will call the server side `php`. Here is my code:

**FORM**

```
<form action="branch_add_verifier.php" method="POST" id="formAdd">
<input type="text" name="id" id="id">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $form = $('#formAdd');
        $form.submit(function(){
            var id= $("#id").val();
            if (id.length < 12) {
                alert("INPUT ERROR");
                return false;
            }

            $.post($form.attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
                alert("DATA SUCCESSFULLY ADDED");
            },'json');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

But the alert message does not pop up inside the `$.post`method
And I also want to know how I can pop up the alert message from the server side. Here is my sample code:

**SERVER SIDE**

```
<?php $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table1
        INNER JOIN table2
        ON table1.col1= table2.col1

        WHERE table2.col3= '".$_REQUEST['id']."'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('ERROR')</script>";
    return false;
} ?>
```

In summary, the code above works but I need to display messages that would tell me if the query is successful or not. Thanks

---

My new problem is that the code below bring me to another page:

**FORM**

```
<form action="branch_add_verifier.php" method="POST" id="formAdd">
<input type="text" name="id" id="id">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#formAdd').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var id= $("#id").val();
            if (id.length < 12) {
                alert("INPUT ERROR");
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
                context: this,
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this),
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (data) {
                if(data == 'ok') {
                   alert("DATA SUCCESSFULLY ADDED");
                }
                if(data == 'no') {
                   alert("ERROR");
                }
            }).fail(function (data) {
                console.log('failed');
            });
        });
    });
```

**SERVER**

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.col1= table2.col1

    WHERE table2.col3= '".$_REQUEST['id']."'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0) {
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo json_encode('no');
    return false;
}
```

I need to return after the json_encode because there are still methods below that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML Form

```
<form action="branch_add_verifier.php" method="POST" id="formAdd">
    <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Script :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $(document).on('submit', "#formAdd", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({  
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: "post",  
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                error:function(){
                    alert("ERROR : CANNOT CONNECT TO SERVER");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
            return false; 
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP server side like this:

```
<?php 
$insert = mysqli_query($conn, "insert query here");
if($insert) {
    echo json_encode('ok');
} else {
    echo json_encode('no');
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks. the code solved my problem but after I press the submit button it directs me to the action url. I need it to stay on the page while calling the server side

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please accept my answer and if you face any problem this code please inform me

Comment: after click submit button if redirect form action url you can share your latest submit script. or follow my answer. i used `e.preventDefault();` after `$('#formAdd').on('submit', function (e) {`. if you use `e.preventDefault();` it stay on this page while calling the server side.

Comment: I copied your solution but it really does bring me to another page.

Comment: show you latest html form and jqeury submit function please and let me know

Comment: I added it in my question

Comment: can you used `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your page header?

Comment: I have tested my answer code, it work fine perfectly in my pc. i thinks you have problem another place

Comment: I solved the problem. Instead of using new FormData(this), I replaced it with $(this).serialize()

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to put `id="id"` in input type text.

```
<input type="text" name="id">
```

**Working Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $form = $('#formAdd');
        $form.submit(function(){
            var id= $("#id").val();
            if (id.length < 12) {
                alert("INPUT ERROR");
                return false;
            }

            $.post($form.attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
                alert("DATA SUCCESSFULLY ADDED");
            },'json');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="branch_add_verifier.php" method="POST" id="formAdd">
<input type="text" id="id" name="id">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hope this works fine for you... Please accept the answer if helpful to you... :) @Benjamin G